# enum not recognised - cypress angular unit test

Tags: angular, cypress

I have been trying to implement cypress-angular-unit-test into my existing Angular 9 app.

I have been getting this issue which I'm not sure how to fix. I keep getting this issue in a file that is totally unrelated to my test case.

**It seems to think that the Enum is undefined, however we can clearly see that it is not**. Also during testing of the app in that area, everything works as expected

also my component and cy-spec.ts files are very simple

any idea why I keep getting this error?I have spent a long time trying to find an answer...

```ts
// cy-spec.ts
describe('KitLabelComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    initEnv(KitLabelComponent, {
      declarations: [HelptipComponent],
    });
  });
  it('shows label with tooltip', () => {
    mount(KitLabelComponent, {
      label: 'test label',
      tooltipText: 'test tooltip',
    });
    cy.contains('test label');
  });
});

/// component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'kit-label',
  template: `
    <label>
      <div>
        <span
          >{{ label }}
          <app-helptip *ngIf="tooltipText" [titleText]="label" [contentText]="tooltipText"></app-helptip>
        </span>
      </div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </label>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./kit-label.component.less'],
})
export class KitLabelComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() tooltipText: string;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you change value to 'sm', does it still complain?

Comment: no it does not complain, however that doesn't fix my issue, i need to use the enum there

Comment: What happens if you try ShotgunBannerIframeSizeEnum["Small"]?